# How many natural numbers from 1 to 10000 there are (with 2 conditions)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many natural numbers from 1 to 10000 there are (with 2 conditions)

**CONDITION 1:**  They do not contain zero.

**CONDITION 2:** Sum of their digits is 9.

So, I went to count manually.

from 0-9 there is just one.

from 10-99 there are 4 * 2! = 8

from 100-999 there are: $D(3,6) = 28$

from 1000-9999 there are: well, here i got a little confused and angry. and decided to ask you guys, if there's a "trick" to find those numbers accurately and fast. because if it would be from 0 to 1 million, or even 10 million, so.. I'm kinda stuck.

Edit: I guess, from 1000-9999 there are $D(4,5) = 56$

So, $56+28+8+1 = 93$ numbers.

Comment: It's just a thought, from 1000-9999 is like: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 9$ and $ x > 0$ so It's like: $D(4,5)$. because if $x > 0$ we must "put for our safety" one ball into every cell. (If zero could be, then it'd be $D(4,9)$).

Comment: What is the function `D(x, y)` that you refer to?

Comment: @EliRose: $C(x+y-1,x-1)$

Comment: Hmm ... it's so interesting that the answer to your question should this pattern! Now I understand the definition of $D(x, y)$, but I'm not sure why it applies here -- could you explain your insight above about putting balls into cells a little more?

Comment: @EliRose Sure. If there are k *identical* balls, and we need to distribute them to $n$ *different* cells. then it is like saying $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = k$. When we see that, we use instantly $D(n,k)$, which is as same as $C(n+k-1,n-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 93.  This isn't a very well motivated answer, but it is true.  The numbers are as follows.

9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 117, 126, 135, 144, 153, 162, 171,
216, 225, 234, 243, 252, 261, 315, 324, 333, 342, 351, 414, 423, 432,
441, 513, 522, 531, 612, 621, 711, 1116, 1125, 1134, 1143, 1152,
1161, 1215, 1224, 1233, 1242, 1251, 1314, 1323, 1332, 1341, 1413,
1422, 1431, 1512, 1521, 1611, 2115, 2124, 2133, 2142, 2151, 2214,
2223, 2232, 2241, 2313, 2322, 2331, 2412, 2421, 2511, 3114, 3123,
3132, 3141, 3213, 3222, 3231, 3312, 3321, 3411, 4113, 4122, 4131,
4212, 4221, 4311, 5112, 5121, 5211, 6111.

Comment: I got it right. Thanks!